# POCO HTMLForm How to read input form element with name like invoice[items][1]

Tags: html, c++, poco-libraries

If my HTML form inputs are like this:

```
<input name='invoice[items][1]' />
<input name='invoice[items][2]' />
<input name='invoice[payments][1]' />
<input name='invoice[payments][2]' />
```

In PHP, I can handle this kind of post or get data like this:

```
$items = $_POST['invoice']['items'];
$payments=$_POST['invoice']['payments'];
```

How can I handle this kind on inputs in Poco Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poco handler will look something like this:

```
void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
{
  HTMLForm form(request, request.stream());
  std::string item1 = form["invoice[items][1]"];
  // ...
}
```

Unlike PHP, C++ does not know anything about your HTML, so it won't parse the names arrays into C++ structures "out of the box"; this can, of course, be easily done with a custom C++ parser and some HTMLForm logic, but it is currently not available in Poco.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, do you know any  custom C++ parser do this (Over a pairs collection) ?

Comment: I don't, you'll have to google it. If you can change the input names to JSON, [Poco::DynamicStruct](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/JSON/testsuite/src/JSONTest.cpp#L447) will do the job fine.